# What does it mean that "VirtualBox" would like to receive keystrokes from any application? Is this safe or malicious?

Tags: security, virtualbox, virtual-machine, macos

I'm using a MacBook, and I'm installing my first virtual machine using virtualboxmanager,
which I received from a Google IT Support Specialist course. 
I'm currently learning about the Linux bash shell (command line interface),
and I've done some work,
but I would like to use it for myself on my own device (pc).

Here is the pop-up received while trying to install a guest OS on macOS 12: 
[image] 
  <sub>Manually transcribed:</sub>

> #### Keystroke Receiving
>
> ---
>
> **"VirtualBox" would like to receive keystrokes from any application.** 
> Grant access to this application in Security & Privacy preferences,
> located in System Preferences. 
>                        …

This is "suspicious" because the verbiage is concerning
(and perhaps inaccurate). 
Is VirtualBox asking to intercept keystrokes entered in any other application running on macOS (for example, Chrome or Microsoft Word)? 
Why would it need to receive keystrokes from other apps?

The process of installing the guest OS seems to be paused
at "Auto capture keyboard" until I deal with this pop-up. 
Is this safe or malicious?  What should I do?

Comment: Don't you need keyboard and mouse to interact with the VM's OS? Yes, you do. Virtualbox automatically enables keyboard and mouse integration for any guest OS with a desktop environment, typically. It asks for any other situations where this seamless integration can't be enabled / not supported. What's wrong with that?

Comment: So what you're saying is that, because the VM's OS is not the primary host on my computer it's asking for permission to use my mouse and keyboard in specific areas that it didn't have those permission?

Comment: Virtual machines are always guests. Host is the OS installed in the bare metal. What I was saying is that requesting access to keyboard and mouse is normal and expected and I can't think of a situation where it wouldn't be.